# Reshape an outer layer of a 3D array to 1D array

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I have a 3D array, like `msh(0:m+1,0:n+1,0:l+1)` which could be a representative of a Cartesian mesh grid.
I would like to reshape the outer layer into 1D array. What could be the best way to do this (efficient from the memory point of view)?

Currently I would reshape plane by plane starting from -z,+z,:

```
array(1:m*n)=reshape(msh(1:m,1:n,0),m*n)   
array(m*n+1:2*m*n)=reshape(msh(1:m,1:n,l+1),m*n)
```

My First question is that weather this reshaping is being done in a memory efficient way! or there is other way like using the do loop which is faster and more memory efficient (the size of the arrays are huge).

Secondly, if I have several of these arrays in different processors what is the best way to gather these outer layers in master node (e.g. `rank=0`) using `MPI`.

Comment: Are these ghost (guard) cells, by any chance? If you're only reshaping the arrays in order to then gather them on the master node, without doing any processing which requires them to be 1D, you may want to look at creating an MPI type. It's pretty easy to create arbitrary 2D slices of a 3D array and gather them.

Comment: Thanks,   No, they are not ghost cells (some plane could be part of the ghost cells), and I have to do some computation on these 1D arrays. I have to keep these arrays for several time steps and do computations on them

Comment: Your method seems fine then. You have a typo in the second line of code, btw, it should be `array(m*n+1:2*m*n)`. Do you need a new array for each plane in your 3D grid? If so, do you need them all at the same time?

Comment: thanks @Yossarian, typo is corrected.

Comment: In general, it is a good idea not to use lowercase letter `l` when indexing arrays. Using this letter decreases code readability and makes it more prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's an [`O(2*m*n+2*l*m+2*l*n)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) problem any way you do it, but *one* option would be to do it a series of loops:

```
allocate(array(2*m*n+2*l*m+2*l*n))
h = 1
do j=1,n
   do i=1,m
      array(h) = msh(i,j,0)
      array(h+m*n+1) = msh(i,j,l+1)
      h = h+1
   enddo
enddo
do k=1,l
   do i=1,m
      array(h) = msh(i,0,k)
      array(h+m*l+1) = msh(i,n+1,k)
      h = h + 1
   enddo
enddo
do k=1,l
   do j=1,n
      array(h) = msh(0,j,k)
      array(h+l*n+1) = msh(m+1,j,k)
      h = h + 1
   enddo
enddo
```

Then use normal mpi subroutines to pass `array` to `master`.

Comment: I did not understand, firstly using the loop is better than using the reshape function? Secondly, your suggestion is that to do the transfer to one dimensional array and then gather to the master node? Or is there any other way to gather them without making them one dimensional!

Comment: @user3244667: Like most intrinsic routines, `reshape` *can* be faster than loops, but it entirely depends on the **size** of the array you are working with (testing it yourself is really the best bet to figure out when one is more advantageous than the other). Personally, I like loops because I can see *what it is I'm doing* more clearly than with intrinsics.

Comment: You could do the mpi call either way, but knowing which indices of the 1D array belong to which boundaries or where each 3D cube belongs in relation to the others in the main processor is a challenge you'll have to work on.